# Nothing showing in playmode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, playback, pause

My script is running fine and had been showing the game up in play mode (but not in scene view) up until I finished the script and now it has disappeared and I can't seem to find it in either.

I made sure I was in orthographic view, tried messing with the near and far values of the clipping planes in the main camera and made sure all assets in the scene including the gameobject housing the script were positioned at 0 on all axis. I can't find it at all anymore, aside from when pressing pause in play mode but then I can't test the interactions.

This is what I see when I enter play mode

[image]

This is what I see when I hit pause

[image]

it's supposed to be shuffled at the beginning so that part seems right as it is a different order every time I try this

Comment: Why are there so many Cameras...? Looks to me like those are overlaying each other and since your sprites are too close to the cameras they are not visible to those => you only get a beautiful rendering of an empty background from your last rendered camera ;)

Comment: There's only one camera in the scene though, and if I delete the extras (that I can only see in playmode) it won't save. Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Comment: Can you click on the objects `0`, `1` etc? At least the have a camera Gizmo in your scene view so they seem to have a camera component

Answer (score 0):

Move the camera back 10 units on the z. Cameras have a view frustum, where elements outside it won't render. This is what is happening here. With the near plane set to 0.3, you need to move the camera away from an object by 0.3 units. The default z value is -10 on the camera.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-nearClipPlane.html

Comment: For some reason it won't allow me to change the xyz or near values anymore, though I had changed the camera z axis from -10 to 0 before to try and sovle the problem. Unsure why I can no longer affect them..